# Converting a DataFrame with a tree-structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have some tree-structured data given as a DataFrame.

```py
   level   id  parent_id  type text
0      1    1       <NA>  node    a
1      2   11          1  node    b
2      2   12          1  node    c
3      2   13          1  leaf    d
4      3  111         11  leaf    e
5      3  121         12  leaf    f
6      3  122         12  leaf    g
```

I'd like to get a DataFrame looking like this:

```py
level       1              2                3            leaf           
attributes id  type text  id  type text    id  type text   id  type text
0           1  node    a  11  node    b   111  leaf    e  111  leaf    e
1           1  node    a  12  node    c   121  leaf    f  121  leaf    f
2           1  node    a  12  node    c   122  leaf    g  122  leaf    g
3           1  node    a  13  leaf    d  <NA>   NaN  NaN   13  leaf    d
```

My current solution looks like this:

```py
from functools import reduce
def join_fn(x, y):
    i, df1 = x
    j, df2 = y
    return (
        j,
        pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=f"id_{i}", right_on=f"parent_id_{j}", how="outer"),
    )

dfs = list(df.groupby("level"))
dfs = [
    (i, df.rename(columns={col: col + f"_{i}" for col in df.columns})) for i, df in dfs
]

_, dfr = reduce(join_fn, dfs)
dfr = dfr.filter([col for col in dfr.columns if col.startswith(("id", "text", "type"))])
idx = dfr.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
dfr.columns = idx.swaplevel()
```

which yields the following:

```py
  1              2                 3           
  id  type text  id  type text     id  type text
0  1  node    a  11  node    b  111.0  leaf    e
1  1  node    a  12  node    c  121.0  leaf    f
2  1  node    a  12  node    c  122.0  leaf    g
3  1  node    a  13  leaf    d    NaN   NaN  NaN
```

How do I get the last three columns, i.e. the ones where the leafs are collected?

Futhermore I'm open for improvements in my current code.

Comment: I don't understand why your graph is not `[['<NA>', 1, 13], ['<NA>', 1, 11, 111], ['<NA>', 1, 2, 121],  ['<NA>', 1, 12, 122]]`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. "<NA>   NaN  NaN" is not the <NA> from parent_id column?

Comment: In the last `DataFrame`? The NA's appear since `13` is already a leaf.

Comment: But just curious: why do you need those 3 extra columns, there are only 3 levels and the leaf types are captured in 'type' column.

Comment: @SomeDude Because I want to merge with another DataFrame on the leaf-id. This is only a toy-example. The real tree is much deeper.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
def merge(ldf, rdf, lsuffix, rsuffix=None):
    return ldf.merge(
        rdf,
        how='right',
        left_on='parent_id',
        right_on='id',
        suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix),
    ).drop(
        columns=[f'parent_id{lsuffix}', f'level{lsuffix}'],
    )

df = df[df.columns[::-1]]

res = df[df['level'] == df['level'].max()]
for lev in range(df['level'].max() - 1, 1, -1):
    res = merge(res, df[df['level'] == lev], f'_{lev + 1}')

res = merge(res, df[df['level'] == 1], '_2', '_1')
res = res.drop(columns=['parent_id_1', 'level_1'])
res = res[res.columns[::-1]]

for prefix in ('id', 'type', 'text'):
    sub_res = res[[c for c in res.columns if c.startswith(prefix)]]
    sub_res[f'{prefix}_leaf'] = [pd.NA] * len(sub_res)
    res[f'{prefix}_leaf'] = sub_res.ffill(axis=1)[f'{prefix}_leaf']
```